# vim can not show correctly with tmux

Tags: ubuntu, vim, tmux

system infomation:

```
uname -a
Linux 3.19.0-61-generic #69~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 9 09:09:13 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

vim version:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by buildd@
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions
```

tmux version is tmux-2.2

vim can be used normally without tmux, and if use tmux, vim will show like this:

[test http://o7ocntpuu.bkt.clouddn.com/images/tmp/error.png](http://o7ocntpuu.bkt.clouddn.com/images/tmp/error.png)

and the error will not happend when I use a putty to login, only I use gnome Terminal. I don't know why this happend

Comment: Did you tried `:redraw` or pressed `Ctrl+L` ? It will redraw the screen.

Comment: This is most likely related to a messed up `termcap` / `terminfo` entry for either `tmux` or `gnome-terminal`.  Report the problem upstream to the (Ubuntu) maintainers of said programs.

Comment: do you have problem with other tool in tmux? if problem is vim only, pls show your vimrc file. There are several options could lead to refreshing/redraw problem. From the screenshot, it seems that some columns were not refreshed. what does this output? `set columns?`

Comment: @Kent, yes, you are right, I checked vimrc file, and I find set col=50, I comment line, then tmux and vim show correctly!Thanks very much!